# jQuery Plugin Method Chaining Class Layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery plugin and I am having trouble setting up the class/methods to fit the api access I would like.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work (I get an Object doesn't support this property or method error):

```
(function( $ ){
    $.kitty= function( name ) {  
        this.name = name;
        this.cat= function( say ) {
            alert(  this.name + ": " + say );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

I want to cause the output using:

```
$.kitty('chairman meow').cat('meow!');
```

output:

```
chairman meow: meow!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
(function($) {
    $.kitty = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cat = function(say) {
            alert(name + ": " + say);
        }
            return this;
    };

})(jQuery);


$(function() {
    $.kitty('chairman meow').cat('meow!');
})​
```

don't forget to return the object.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aXSry/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.kitty = function(name) {  
    return {
        name: name,
        cat: function(say) {
            alert(this.name + ": " + say);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Big hugs for speed and JSON notation :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, because you are trying to call the function cat of the return value of $.kitty. Since $.kitty doesn't return anything, there is no function cat to call. It would work if you return this in $.kitty, but I don't think that is the correct way to write a jquery pluging. Take a look at [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) if you want to know how it works...

Comment: Seems like everybody knew this but me! Now I am smarter thanks to you :D